# couldn't delete an element from table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have put a link to delete an element from a mysql table

```
<td><a href="suppoffre.php?adresse='.$commande["Adresse"].'"><img src="images/delete.png"</td>
```

Here is the page suppoffre.php

```
<?php


#Connexion avec la base de données
include('connexion.php');

#Récupération des données par la méthode POST
$adresse=$_GET['adresse'];

#Supprimer un offre 
$sql = "DELETE 
        FROM agence
    WHERE Adresse = ".$adresse;

//exécution de la requête:
    $requete = mysql_query($sql);

     //affichage des résultats, pour savoir si la suppression a marchée:
     if($requete)
            {
           echo("La suppression à été correctement effectuée") ;
                }
              else
                    {
           echo("La suppression à échouée") ;
              }?>
```

the error I'm getting is La suppression à échoué

Comment: change the line `WHERE Adresse = ".$adresse;` to `WHERE Adresse = $adresse";` You were adding the `"` on the wrong place I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Address is string as I think so you need to do like

```
$sql = "DELETE 
    FROM agence
WHERE Adresse = '".$adresse."'";
```

You need to escape the string with `mysql_real_escape_string` like

```
$sql = "DELETE 
        FROM agence
        WHERE Adresse = '".mysql_real_escape_string($adresse)."'";
```

And also try to avoid using mysql_* statements because they are **deprecated** ,instead of them use **mysqli**_* functions or **PDO** statements

**EDIT:** Using mysqli_* you can try like

```
$result = $mysqli->query("DELETE 
                          FROM agence
                          WHERE Adresse = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($adresse)."'");

if($result) {
    echo("La suppression à été correctement effectuée") ;
} else {
    echo("La suppression à échouée") ;
}
```

Follow this [**GUIDE**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) for better knowing of mysqli_* functions

Comment: Try adding an example using PDO or Mysqli too :) that should be better.

Comment: Thanku for your suggestion @KeesSonnema ....See my edited ans

Comment: @KeesSonnema have you seen my edit..??

Comment: you can up it even .. ;-)

Comment: Thanks  Gautam You're right, it's quite better, mysql statements are so depricated as you said !

Comment: Yes....mysqli_* functions also easy to learn.they are like mysql_* only...

Answer (score 0):

Adresse is string so use quote in your query

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM agence WHERE Adresse = '".$adresse."'";
```